# how to find rows not exist or different in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have two tables. 
One is `inventorytable` with columns `PO No,index,item name,amount,date`,

```
PO  Index   Item    amount  date       unit price
PO01    1   pen     20      1/2/2018    10
PO01    2   pad     15      1/3/2018    10
PO02    1   book    30      2/5/2018    10
```

Another table is `paymentrecord` with `PO No,index,item name, amount, value`.

```
PO  Index   Item    amount  
PO01    1   pen      10 
PO01    2   pad      15
```

How to find inventory not paid or not fully paid?

```
PO  Index   Item    amount   unpaid value 
PO01    1   pen     10        100
PO02    1   book    30        3000
```

I tried following sql

```
select * 
from inventory 
where not exists (select inventory.PONo,inventory.index 
                  from inventory,payment
                  where inventory.PO=payment.PO )
```

but it returns nothing

Comment: You should explain **'not exist'** and  **'different'**.  What are you comparing ? every column ? only table keys?

Comment: @APC : I posted that comment 3 hours ago. The question only had the query then, without any data. I will delete the comment anyway as it is irrelevant now.

Comment: @kaushik - sorry. I am using the SE app which makes it harder to see what editing has been done.

Answer (score 1):

Use an outer join to link payments to inventory. Filter on `payment.amount` being less than the calculated value of the inventory items, `unit_price * amount`:

```
select i.po_no
       , i.Index
       , i.Item
       , i.amount
       , ((i.unit_price * i.amount) - nvl(p.amount, 0) as  unpaid_value 
from inventory i
      left join payment p
          on p.po_no = i.po_no
          and p.index = i.index
where (i.unit_price * i.amount) > nvl(p.amount, 0)
/
```

Note: the names of things are inconsistent across all your examples. So you may need to tweak this solution to make it run on your schema.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need both, PO and Index, to uniquely identify record. 
Try out below.

```
select * from inventory 
where not exists 
(select 1 from inventory,payment where inventory.PO=payment.PO and inventory.Index=payment.Index)
```

Comment: This should fix the query returning no rows but alas the OP had gone down the wrong road: this query still won't give them the records they need to produce their desired result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
select i.ipo, i.iindex, i.iitem, 
(i.iamount - coalesce(p.pamount,0)) as Tamount
from payment p right outer join invent i
on (i.ipo = p.ppo and i.iindex = p.pindex and i.iitem = p.pitem)
where i.iamount != coalesce(p.pamount,0)
```

This is result in

```
ipo iindex  iitem   Tamount
PO01    1   pen 10
PO02    1   book    30
```

Table structure followed is

```
create table invent
(
iPO  varchar(4),
iIndex   int, 
iItem   varchar(10),
iamount  int,
idate       date,
iunit_price int);

create table payment
(
pPO  varchar(4),
pIndex   int,
pItem    varchar(10),
pamount  int);
```

Comment: Looks remarkably like my solution from two hours ago except it uses `right outer join` instead of `left outer join`.

Comment: Accept my apologies because I didn't go through the answers, I will delete this one if you want.

Answer (score -1):

Hope following query helps. Use same column name instead of *.

```
select * from inventory
Except
select * from payment
```

Comment: I think you mean **minus** not **except**

Comment: The tables have different projections so any set operation like this won't compile. Also it won't produce the OP's desired output which includes a calculation of the unpaid difference.